# Gatling 2 - Mapping values to template

Tags: scala, gatling

I am considering moving to [Gatling](https://github.com/excilys/gatling) 2.0.0-M3a, but I am having issues getting a basic test working.  The issue I am having is mapping values to a template file in Gatling 2.  The examples below show how I achieved this in Gatling 1.5, but I can't figure it out in 2.

**LoginScenario.scala** - works in gatling 1.5

```
package StressTesting

import com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.Predef._
import com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http.Predef._
import Headers._
import akka.util.duration._
import bootstrap._

object LoginScenario {

    val scn = scenario("Login")
        .feed(csv("user_credentials.csv"))
        .exec(
            http("login")
                .post("/api/login")
                .fileBody("loginTemplate",
                    Map(
                        "userName" -> "${userName}",
                        "password" -> "${password}"
                        )
                    ).asJSON
                .headers(post_header)
                .check(status.is(200)))
    }
```

**LoginScenario.scala** - ERRORS - Reworked version to accommodate changes between Gatling 1.5 and 2

```
package StressTesting

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import Headers._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import bootstrap._
import io.gatling.core.session.Expression

object LoginScenario {

  val scn = scenario("Login")
    .feed(csv("user_credentials.csv"))
    .exec(
      http("login")
        .post("/api/login")
            .body(ELFileBody("request-bodies/loginTemplate.ssp", 
        Map("userName" -> "${userName}","password" -> "${password}"))).asJSON
        .headers(post_header)
        .check(status.is(200))
    )
}
```

**loginTemplate.ssp** - Template used in both examples

```
{
  "userName": "<%= userName %>",
  "password": "<%= password %>",
  "platformCode": "app",
  "clientInformation": {
    "operatingSystem": "OSX",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "10.8",
    "browser": "Chrome",
    "browserVersion": "31",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've dropped Scalate in Gatling 2, as it was really cumbersome.

Please have a look at our wiki for the new syntax: https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Gatling-2#wiki-bodies

Basically, you can write regular Gatling EL in you template, and you no longer have to explicitly pass parameters:

```
.body(ELFileBody("request-bodies/loginTemplate.txt"))
```

loginTemplate.txt:

```
{
  "userName": "${userName}",
  "password": "${password}",
  "platformCode": "app",
  "clientInformation": {
    "operatingSystem": "OSX",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "10.8",
    "browser": "Chrome",
    "browserVersion": "31",
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we use .body(ELFileBody("request-bodies/loginTemplate.json")), and not .txt format?

Comment: Values like ${id} need to be in the session. One way to do it is by doing
.exec(_.set("id", UUID.randomUUID()))

Comment: It's ElFileBody as of 2.2

Answer (score 5):

It is `ElFileBody` not `ELFileBody`. Check the case